# C++ training from scratch to quantitative trading?

Tags: trading, programming, quantitative

I have been trading for decades, and I have a solid knowledge of technical analysis but also VB as professional programmer.

I would like to start learning C++ from scratch, then specialised in C++ for quant. trading

Any hint about where to start from please ?

- Learning C++ just enough to move to quant trading
- Learning C++ for quant trading

Answer (score 6):

**C++**

[Think in C++](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) can be a starting point. This is free. And, you might study **Beginning Visual C++ 2010** by Ivan Horton

**Quantitative finance and C++** (if you are derivatives-oriented)

You might find **Mark Joshi** as well as **Daniel Duffy**'s writings of (great) interest.
It is easy to find the references of both their books on a website such as Amazon.
You can also visit Mark Joshi's [website](http://www.markjoshi.com), and Daniel Duffy's [one](http://www.datasimfinancial.com/).

Comment: That is absolutely great, thank you very much . I am ordering those books right now. Best regards Phil